# Modify Mozilla preferences from extension

Tags: preferences, thunderbird-addon

This is difficult to research, because all the keywords are quite generic...

A Thunderbird extension that I just wrote warrants changes in Thunderbird's main preferences dialog, because one particular setting collides with the extension's function and renders the latter useless if chosen/set.

I would like to do one or better both of these things:

1) Untick a checkbox and change the state of a radio button.

2) Altogether deactivate a checkbox or a radio button.

I found the following code snippet, which might do what I intend (at least for point 1) above):

```
var pref = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
pref.setIntPref("dom.max_script_run_time", 30);
```

If it does, I still have the problem of finding out the IDs of the preferences I want to change. The DOM-Inspector extension obviously does not work on the open preferences dialog window... so how do I know which preference to set?

And how do I overlay the preferences dialog in order to deactivate widgets? Is this at all possible? Or can I deactivate widgets programmatically (as soon as I have their ID?)

Comment: "DOM-Inspector extension obviously does not work on the open preferences dialog window" - why "obviously"? DOM Inspector works fine with the Preferences window. You have to open DOM Inspector first, then open Preferences, select the right tab and switch to the DOM Inspector. In the DOM Inspector you select the chrome window you want to inspect - meaning the Preferences window.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work for me yesterday, now it does - strange. I'll try to go from here :-)